# Elasticsearch CreateIndex() not enough arguments

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am trying to use Elasticsearch for GO with this well-known [repo](https://github.com/olivere/elastic)

However, when I am trying to create an `index` ([docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#Client.CreateIndex), and also given as an example [here](https://github.com/olivere/elastic)):

```
    // Define an elastic client 
    client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("host1"))
    if err != nil {
        client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("host2"))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error when connecting Elasticsearch host");    
        }
    }

    // Create an index
    _, err = client.CreateIndex("events").Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error when creating Elasticsearch index"); 
        panic(err)
    }
```

I got the following error, which I do not understand:

> not enough arguments in call to client.CreateIndex("events").Do

Why is that? What do I miss here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IndicesCreateService.Do()` function](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/1368b91516f39100baf5e23a02ae9f090c0d90e2/indices_create.go#L80) expects a `context.Context` to be passed.

So, you need to import `"golang.org/x/net/context"` and then change your call to this:

```
import (
    ... your other imports...    
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)
...
_, err := client.CreateIndex("events").Do(context.TODO())
                                                ^
                                                |
                                             add this
```

You can also check the [`indices_create_test.go`](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/1368b91516f39100baf5e23a02ae9f090c0d90e2/indices_create_test.go) test case in order to see how it's done.

Comment: Thanks! Although I do not get the `.TODO()`. What that should be? (And thanks for the advice about the testcases)

Comment: That simply returns an non-null, empty context that you can use: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context#TODO