# Golang error "not enough arguments in call"

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I'm new to golang. Trying to implement a bulk upload to Elasticsearch by golang. I'm using golang library -> https://github.com/olivere/elastic for communication with Elasticsearch.

Also, a piece of sample code which I'm trying but getting following error...

```
suresh@BLR-245:~/Desktop/tools/golang/src$ go install github.com/crazyheart/elastic-bulk-upload
# github.com/crazyheart/elastic-bulk-upload
github.com/crazyheart/elastic-bulk-upload/main.go:29: not enough arguments in call to bulkRequest.Do
    have ()
    want ("golang.org/x/net/context".Context)
suresh@BLR-245:~/Desktop/tools/golang/src$
```

My Golang Code(main.go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5"
    "strconv"
)

type Tweet struct {
    User    string `json:"user"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func main() {
    client, err := elastic.NewClient()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("%v", err)
    }

    n := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        bulkRequest := client.Bulk()
        for j := 0; j < 10000; j++ {
            n++
            tweet := Tweet{User: "olivere", Message: "Package strconv implements conversions to and from string representations of basic data types. " + strconv.Itoa(n)}
            req := elastic.NewBulkIndexRequest().Index("twitter").Type("tweet").Id(strconv.Itoa(n)).Doc(tweet)
            bulkRequest = bulkRequest.Add(req)
        }
        bulkResponse, err := bulkRequest.Do()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if bulkResponse != nil {

        }
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Anybody, help me to understand what that error means & how to solve those?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40610924/4604579

Comment: @Val - Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: No prob, glad to help!

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. What is your question?

Comment: My question is about golang error message "not enough arguments in call"? As I'm new to golang I couldn't able to understand what it's exactly. Anyway, It's fixed now.

Comment: @DownVoters - It'll be great to mention the reason of making down votes. So that, If I made anything wrong in question than I can fix that.

Comment: @Flimzy It's just 5 days I've started with golang. I've no idea about  golang's 'context' & error displaying technique. So, when I saw error message like this ```have () want ("golang.org/x/net/context".Context)``` I got confused. Don't you think, fig. out the solution from error message require some short of prior information about the programming language & which can be achieved in a certain level of experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a context to bulkRequest.Do().

From the olivere/elastic Github page (abbreviated);

`// Create a context
     ctx := context.Background()
     bulkRequest.Do(ctx)`

Comment: Thanks. Exactly, I made mistake at here. It's working now.